# How can I process an image uploaded to wordpress via url?

Tags: wordpress

After an image is uploaded to Wordpress I want to do some initial processing to it. Namely trim its white background. I search and found I can hook into `wp_handle_upload` like so:

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload', 'handle_upload' );

function handle_upload( $resource ) {
  // process image

  return $resource;
}
```

And everything works great if I manually upload an image to the Wordpress library. But it seems like this is not called at all if the images are uploaded from an url using an import plugin.

Any idea how to solve this problem ? Shouldn't my solution also cover that instance ?

Comment: It would be very tough to say without knowing what import plugin you're using - can you fill in some more details?

Comment: The plugin is WP All Import

Comment: Plugin function that fires once an attachment has been added: https://git.silkco.de/silkcode/zemic-wp/blob/1760cf205aa1aa2dc749667291c8284adca1c80b/wp-content/plugins/wp-all-import-pro/actions/add_attachment.php

Answer (score 0):

Not sure without knowing more about the plugin in question, but there also exists a handle for sideloaded images, wp_handle_sideload:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_sideload

Perhaps this is what you're interested in? It doesn't fire on a direct upload, but rather imported files from other sources.

Comment: I have seen that function, but I'm not sure how to hook into it, or how exactly to use it in order to achieve the same result

Comment: Adding `add_filter( 'wp_handle_sideload', 'handle_upload' );` doesn't have any effect on the uploaded images from url with WP All Import

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer. The corresponding WP All Import function for `wp_handle_upload` is `wp_all_import_handle_upload`. Thanks!